# "Hillbilly” Darkwing villain with pet alligator

Tags: character-identification, darkwing-duck

I only saw this character in a couple of episodes and never learned his name. He was based on the stereotypical Cajun hillbilly, spoke with an equally stereotypical bayou accent and kept an alligator as a pet/sidekick.

Comment: If he's a cajun, he ain't no hillbilly.  Ain't no hills in Louisiana.  Redneck, maybe.  Hick, maybe.  Hillbilly?  Nope.

Comment: @JRE- does it matter? They're equally derogatory terms.

Comment: Derogatory terms, but different types.  And, if you call a redneck a hillbilly, he will be insulted and wonder how you could possibly get the two mixed up when he (the redneck) is obviously better than the hillbilly (and the hillbilly will think the same.

Comment: Besides, if you are going to insult someone you should at last know the meaning of the insults you are throwing around.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - I've rolled back your edit. Making substantive changes to the question *once you've got the answer* is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [**Jambalaya Jake**](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Jambalaya_Jake)

> Jambalaya Jake lived in the bayou along with his pet alligator Gumbo
>   (who seems to be much smarter than him), but the two decide to move to
>   the big city after hearing it was easy pickings. The two make their
>   hideout in the sewers of St. Canard, where they plot their crimes.
>   Jake and Gumbo first appear in the episode "Can't Bayou Love." By
>   using Launchpad McQuack as bait, they try and catch Darkwing Duck. But
>   Darkwing shows them first hand that in the city it is not so "easy
>   pickings."

[image]

[image]